# Android implement exact timer

Tags: java, android

I was writing sort of a timer app and faced a problem. There is background thread, that perform operation such as

```
timer.tick();
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
```

I knew that sleep can be inexact. But every 50 minutes we loose approximately 5 minutes, that in my case is intolerable.
And even when I tried for experiment

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < millis) { /* NOP */ }
```

We loose approximately 12 seconds each 15 minutes.
What is the way to implement exact background timer on Android?

Comment: maybe isntead of counting time, you might want to wait for a targeted time? if a user sets 15 timer on 20:31. create a Date object for 21:46 and wait until that time is passed. and instead of doing a noop loop or sleeping you could use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: @Dodge case here is that I perform tracking action each second, update UI, write statistics, etc.